# Existence of integral extension of DVR satisfying some conditions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $X^{\prime}$ and $X$ be integral noether schemes over $\mathbb{C}$, and $p:X^{\prime}\rightarrow X$ be a surjective morphism.
Let $R$ be any discrete valuation ring over $\mathbb{C}$ with its fraction field $K$, and $i:\operatorname{Spec}K \rightarrow X$ is given.
I'm trying to prove the following claim, but I have a problem.

> There exists an integral extension $R\subset R'$, where $R'$ is another discrete valuation ring over $\mathbb{C}$  with fraction field $K'$, and a morphsim $j: \operatorname{Spec}K^{\prime} \rightarrow X$ of $\mathbb{C}$-schemes, such that
> the following diagram commutes:
> $\require{AMScd}$
> \begin{CD}
>   \operatorname {Spec}K^{\prime} @>\displaystyle j>> X^{\prime}\\
>   @V \displaystyle V V\ @VV
> \displaystyle{p} V\\
>   \operatorname {Spec}K@>>\displaystyle i> X
>   \end{CD}

My try :
Let $x\in X$ be the image of $i$. Since $p$ is surjective, there is a closed point $x^{\prime}\in X^{\prime}$ such that $p(x^{\prime})=x$. Then,$k(x)\subset k(x^{\prime})$ and $K \subset K^{\prime}:=k(x^{\prime})\otimes K$ is a finite algebraic extension.
We get $R\subset K^{\prime}$. Set $R^{\prime}$ as the integral closure of $R\hookrightarrow K^{\prime}$.

But I'm not sure if $R^{\prime}$ is DVR, and I'm stuck.
Any advice and comments are applicated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. This seems like it might be better suited for MSE and your attempt is a bit of a mess. $R'$ need not be a DVR (consider the integral closure of $k[t^2-1]_{(t^2-1)}$ in $k(t)$). 2. It's somewhat strange you picked noetherian instead of finite type. Are you really only assuming noetherian and not finite type?

Comment: Thanks. Excuse me, but I should ask at MSE. If I assume $R$ and $X$ is of finite type over $k$, is this true?

Comment: Yes, see for instance the strategy outlined in Hartshorne exercise II.4.11(a).

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3691688/lifting-of-meromorphic-function-along-a-finite-morphism